# Is there any purpose to Lazy<T> in this sample code?

Tags: .net, msdn

One of the examples for using `Task` I found on MSDN [(found here)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/hh873173.aspx) seems rather odd. Is there any reason for the `Lazy<T>` class to be used here?

```
public class AsyncCache<TKey, TValue>
{
    private readonly Func<TKey, Task<TValue>> _valueFactory;
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, Lazy<Task<TValue>>> _map;

    public AsyncCache(Func<TKey, Task<TValue>> valueFactory)
    {
        if (valueFactory == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("loader");
        _valueFactory = valueFactory;
        _map = new ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, Lazy<Task<TValue>>>();
    }

    public Task<TValue> this[TKey key]
    {
        get
        {
            if (key == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
            return _map.GetOrAdd(key, toAdd => 
                new Lazy<Task<TValue>>(() => _valueFactory(toAdd))).Value;
        }
    }
}
```

As soon as the `Lazy<Task<TValue>>` is created it is immediately accessed. If it's being accessed immediately then using `Lazy<T>` only adds overhead and is making this example more confusing than it needs to. Unless I am missing something here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that it is created then immediately accessed, but the important thing to note is ***you don't always use the object you create***.

Dictionary's `GetOrAdd` function acts like a `Lazy<T>` with [`LazyThreadSafetyMode.PublicationOnly`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.lazythreadsafetymode(v=vs.110).aspx) which means the delegate you pass in as the factory function may be executed more than once but only the first to finish will be returned to all callers.

The default behavior of `Lazy<T>` is `LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication` which means the first person to call the factory function will obtain a lock and any other callers have to wait till the factory function finishes before continuing on.

If we reformat the get method it becomes a little more clear.

```
public Task<TValue> this[TKey key]
{
    get
    {
        if (key == null) 
           throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
        var cacheItem = _map.GetOrAdd(key, toAdd => 
                             new Lazy<Task<TValue>>(() => _valueFactory(toAdd)));
        return cacheItem.Value;
    }
}
```

So if two threads both call `this[Tkey key]` at the same time and they both reach `GetOrAdd` with no value in the dictionary with the passed in key then `new Lazy<Task<TValue>>(() => _valueFactory(toAdd))` ***will be executed twice***, however only the first one to complete gets returned to both calls. This is not a big deal because `_valueFactory` is not executed yet and that is the expensive portion, all we are doing is making a new `Lasy<T>`.

Once the `GetOrAdd` call returns you will always be working with the same single object, that is when `.Value` is called, this uses `ExecutionAndPublication` mode and will block any other calls to `.Value` until `_valueFactory` finshes executing.

If we did not use the `Lazt<T>` then `_valueFactory` would have gotten executed multiple times before a single result was returned.

Answer (score 1):

`ConcurrentDictionary` does not guarantee that your value factory executes only once. This is in order to avoid calling user code under an internal lock. This can lead to deadlocks which is bad API design.

Multiple lazies can be created but only one of them will actually be materialized because the dictionary only ever returns one of them.

This ensures guaranteed one-time execution. It's a standard pattern.